# Code exits without printing expected result

Tags: java

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I have a very simple piece of code that keeps terminating on the console window.

```
public class IsUnique {
public int add(){
    return 4;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    IsUnique a = new IsUnique();
    a.add();
}
```

}

Comment: you call `add` but dont print out the value returned...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your code doesn't even do anything... so yeah.

Comment: Oh yeah major brain fart. I just had to add System.out.println. Totally forgot...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IsUnique {
    public int add(){
        return 4;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        IsUnique a = new IsUnique();
        a.add();

        System.out.println(a);

        // Wait until user hits key before quitting
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```